# How to extend or prototype a HTML table

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extend

Is is possible to extend a native HTML table?

C# example: `public class: htmltable{}`

or something like:

```
HTMLTable.prototype.myType=function(){
 this.clss='myClass';
 this.setAttribute('class',this.clss);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, the degree to which you can tinker with the DOM stuff varies quite a bit between IE and the browsers that don't suck. But what is your ultimate goal here? If this worked, it would just be a method to use instead of hitting .className directly. It wouldn't automatically hit all tables on a page with that class or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where browsers have implemented an inheritance scheme for DOM elements, you can usually extend them according to that scheme. Most modern browsers implement prototype inheritance that is consistent with ECMA-262, **however** do not use it because:

1. User agents are not required to implement inheritance, many (most?) don't. Note that there are many user agents other than browsers
2. Even if browsers do implement inheritance, there's no requirement for it to be consistent with ECMA-262 (though it would be sensible to do so)
3. Your extensions may clash with current or future host object extensions in some or all browsers

Prototype.js uses DOM element inheritance in UAs that support it, and uses a fallback of "extending" DOM elements themselves where they don't. It has recently abandoned that strategy for the reasons noted above. It was also error prone and slow.

Comment: Are they still updating Prototype?

Answer (score 0):

I am building an online cad program that is an elevation. The elevation has bays that contain doors, windows, and horizontals that split up the bays. Using a table is perfect for this situation, "until the browsers start implementing the workers and local storage along with the canvas".

I am using an Array for my storage of each bay, ie: the dims,horizontal count,door or window count. So when resizing or something takes place i have to loop through the array of bays and reset all their properties, if need be. Then I have to update the actual td for viewing. Basically I update it in the core and pass it back to the UI and it does what ever it needs to up the updated info.

I was just making sure that I could not extend the htmltd before I went to far with this. I was thinking it would be nice to do away with the array, and maybe that would not be the best way either but it looks like I'll never know. ;)

Something like the below code is what I was after.

```
this.myWidth;

var bays = this.rows[0].cells, len=bays.length, bay;
for(i=0; i< len;i++){

    this.myWidth = someThingCalculated from a parameter;
    bay = bays[i];
    bay.style.width= ((this.myWidth / elevationWidth) * 100)) + %;
};
```